# Python Watchdog spawn multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, pathos

I am writing files (at a really fast pace) to a specific directory. I would like to monitor the directory for new files and then spawn a process that runs an external script. Right now, I am getting a pickling error (even though I am using Pathos) of

```
Can't pickle <type 'Struct'>: it's not found as __builtin__.Struct
```

I need help fixing the pickling error which may cause me to have to rethink what I am doing, which is fine.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import argparse
import json
import time
import os
from datetime import datetime
#Test for Pathos
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from subprocess import check_output
import ConfigParser
import logging
#WatchDog
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemMovedEvent

from CodernityDB.database import Database

###
# CONFIGURATION
###

CONFIG GOES HERE BUT REMOVED 

###
# Custom handler for Python Watchdog
# When spawned, it will spawn a new worker into the pool
###
class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
        def __init__(self):
                self.db = Database("/var/db/test.db")
                try:
                        self.db.open()
                except Exception, e:
                        print str(e)
                        self.db.create()

        def on_created(self, event):
                #print event.src_path
                try:
                        pool.map(doIt, (self.db, event.src_path,))
                except Exception, e:
                        print str(e)

def codernityIt(db, json_):
        try:
                print json_
                db.insert(json_)
        except Exception, e:
                print str(e)
                logging.error(str(e))

def doIt(db, file_):
        try:
                codernityIt(db, json.loads(check_output(['python', '/external/script.py', file_])))
        except Exception, e:
                print str(e)
                logging.error(str(e))

if __name__ == '__main__':
        ###
        # Pool specific Settings
        ###
        pool = Pool(processes=cpu_count())
        event_handler = MyHandler()
        ###
        # Watchdog specific settings
        ###
        observer = Observer()
        observer.schedule(event_handler, path=watchPath, recursive=True)
        observer.start()

        ###
        # This While True loop listens for Keyboard interrupts and will gracefully exit the program if found
        ###
        try:
                while True:
                        time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                observer.unschedule_all()
                observer.stop()
                db.close()
        #observer.join()
```

Comment: I don't know how to fix your pickling error, but if you want to watch a directory, you might consider doing it through another script and repeatedly checking the output of os.listdir() for file changes. It's less efficient, but simpler if your use case is simple enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try inotify?
It may help you: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inotify

Comment: I ended up changing my script to use PYINotify and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that it's failing because `dill` (which `pathos` uses) doesn't know how to pickle a `Struct`.  It's one of the few objects that I don't think `dill` can currently handle, as it is not defined where it lives in the namespace… see: https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/24.